# Chromium patch number and equivalent download

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

My understanding is the [latest stable release](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2018/04/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_26.html) of Chrome is [66.0.3359 with PATCH 139](https://www.chromium.org/developers/version-numbers) (e.g. 66.0.3359.139).

**Question 1**

Is it possible to download the equivalent Chromium version of this PATCH on the [Chromium nightly snapshots index](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/)?

For example, I see about 40 builds of 3359 (540045-540438) in `chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/chrome-win32.zip`, all with the same manifest `66.0.3359.0.manifest`.

**Question 2**

Does the increase in number (540045-540438) represent a newer PATCH or are they just different builds of the same BUILD 3359, PATCH 0?

I'm aware of [this site](https://chromium.woolyss.com/) where you can download stable builds of Chromium with the 139 patch, but where does he get the patch for building 3359 with patch 139?

**Edit**

I also found [this](http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/viewer), which sheds a little light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to Question 1:**

Snaphosts are development versions of Chromium. You cannot find a stable version there.

**Answer to Question 2:**

Please, read the [official doc](https://www.chromium.org/developers/version-numbers). In short, "PATCH 0" is only for development version.

The site you mentioned (I am its admin) has stable builds of Chromium because developers recompile Chromium based on the stable version. How? [All is simply explained here](https://chromium.woolyss.com/#stable-chromium-version).

[OmahaProxy CSV Viewer](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/viewer) is the official overview of different development  steps of Google Chrome and Chrome OS (Chromium Dev, Google Canary, Google Beta, Google Chrome...), on each platform.